# iOS - best practice to display formatted data

Tags: ios, uiwebview, formatting, uilabel

i need to display some formatted data on one view. Some headlines, links and some bold and italic text. I wonder what would be the best way to achieve this.

I, right now, see two possibilities: Formatting in HTML and using UIWebView or placing some formatted UILabels.

Are there any other good ways in accomplishing this requirement?

I wonder what your learnings could be using either one of this or both ways.

BR, ~m

Answer (score 1):

I like to use UIWebViews to display rich text.  I include an HTML template with my app bundle, complete with CSS and then have placeholders in the  to hold the various parts of an article.

```
 <body>
   <h1>%@</h1> // Header
   <p>%@</p>   // Article content
 </body>
```

You can also use attributed labels, one being TTTAttributedLabel.
https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/

Comment: isn't it a bit magic in the code to pass the right value to the right placeholder? or do you use some special template engine for mapping value to placeholder?

Comment: I use [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@", HTML_STRING, H1_STRING, P_STRING];

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) - its much nicer (IMHO) to use that a UIWebView, and you can do really fancy things with it. Essentially it uses NSAttributedStrings as text representations, and you can either build those by hand or have this framework convert HTML to that. Lots of options to get callbacks when user taps images or links too.